# Trouble wrapping std::istream, unique_ptr not null after moved

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, iostream, smart-pointers

Since std::istream can't be moved (protected function), I was trying to wrap the std::istream so that I can build my code upon customized stream factory.

So far I have tried inheriting directly from std::istream like this:

```cpp
class IStream : public std::istream{
public:
  // template <typename T>
  IStream(std::istringstream&& rhs) : std::istream(std::move(rhs)){
    this->rdbuf(rhs.rdbuf());
    rhs.istream::rdbuf(NULL);
  }
  IStream(IStream&& rhs) : std::istream(std::move(rhs)){
    this->rdbuf(rhs.rdbuf());
    rhs.rdbuf(NULL);
  }
};
```

But it causes a segmentation fault (any insights on the reason would be appreciated), so I move on to some "safer-looking" method.

Here is the code I currently use:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <istream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class IStream {
 public:
    IStream(const IStream& rhs) = delete;
  template <typename T>
  IStream(T& rhs) : shared_(rhs) {
    std::cout << "called IStream(T&)" << std::endl;
  }
  // assume strict order between member construct for now
  template <typename T>
  IStream(T&& rhs) : owned_{std::make_unique<T>(std::move(rhs))}, shared_(*owned_) {
    std::cout << "called IStream(T&&)" << std::endl;
  }
  IStream(IStream&& rhs) : owned_(std::move(rhs.owned_)), shared_(*owned_) {
    assert(rhs.owned_.get() == nullptr); // failed
    std::cout << "called IStream(IStream&&)" << std::endl;
  }
  std::istream& get() {
    return shared_;
  }
  ~IStream() {
    std::cout << "called ~IStream with " << (owned_.get()!=nullptr) << std::endl;
  }
 private:
  std::unique_ptr<std::istream> owned_;
  std::istream& shared_;
};

IStream&& wrap() {
    return IStream(istringstream{"test"});
}

int main(void) {

    IStream is(wrap());
    char buf[10];
    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(char) * 10);
    is.get().getline(buf, 10);
    std::cout << std::string(buf) << std::endl; 

    return 0;
}
```

Sad thing is this code still won't work, and I found that assertion at `IStream::IStream(IStream&&)` failed.

Output:

```sh
called IStream(T&&)
called ~IStream with 1
Assertion failed: rhs.owned_.get() == nullptr, file .\tmp.cpp, line 23
```

Which leads to wierd phenomenon where unique_ptr is not null after moved.

I am using MSVC compiler btw.

Comment: You say "Since `std::istream` can't be moved" but then the first function in your code attempts to move a `std::istream` (and you try to move the istream several more times in the rest of the code)

Comment: Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then read about [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and edit your question to elaborate on the *real* problem you're trying to solve. *Why* do you need to "move" the stream?

Comment: `shared_(*owned_)` means that `shared` will refer to whatever object the unique_ptr is managing at that point of construction.  If you later modify the unique_ptr then `shared_` will be a dangling reference

Comment: Have you considered moving the unique pointer instead of moving its contents? That old unique pointer will destroy the istream.

Comment: I need a stream factory which returns either a raw pointer/unique_ptr to stream or a rvalue stream, clearly latter is more elegent.

Comment: `wrap()` also returns a dangling reference

Comment: I don't think it will ever be dangling, reference has the same lifetime as unique_ptr as the entire object.

Comment: `rhs.rdbuf()` is UB after `std::istream(std::move(rhs))`

Comment: Also I made the assumption that compiler will construct the pointer and reference the order I specify.

Comment: Why not have `IStream::get` be implemented as `return *owned_;` instead of bothering with `shared_` at all? I think reading about the XY problem as suggested above and rethinking your problem with your new knowledge is likely your best bet here. I don't understand what they point of what you're trying to do is at all.

Comment: BTW `IStream` seems identical to `std::unique_ptr` except for different semantics of `get()`,  maybe you could have your project just use `std::unique_ptr` in the first place without any extra wrapper

Comment: @M.M Amazing, solved it.

Comment: @Omnifarious the original intent was to be able to wrap around static streams like `cin`.

Comment: @tabokie - Why do you need to wrap around them? Why not just pass around an ordinary old `::std::istream &`? Is it that you want the reference to have ownership semantics if you constructed your own thing, but not if you're using `::std::cin`?

Comment: @Omnifarious Right. That is actually a corner case, mostly wrapper is used to unify different streams from factory.

Comment: Rolled back -- please do not edit answers into the question. (This site uses a Question/Answer format)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot sanely do what you want.

As I understand it, you want some sort of object that is as indistinguishable from a `::std::istream` as possible, but has move semantics so that it will be automatically destroyed after it's no longer needed.

The primary useful attribute of anything that can be referred to as an `::std::istream` is that it is derived from `::std::istream`, and since it is `::std::istream` that can't be moved, nothing derived from it can be moved either.

So, you're left with the next best thing, a `::std::unique_ptr` to your `::std::istream` thing. This means you'll have to use `*` all the time and it will be ugly. Oh, well.

No amount of cleverness will allow you to create any kind of wrapper that is simultaneously moveable, and derived from `::std::istream` so that it works with all the nice existing library functions that expect that. Nor can you make something that acts in any reasonable way like a reference without that thing actually being a reference.

BTW, when you construct a `unique_ptr` you can provide a custom deleter if you're actually pointing at something like `::std::cin` that you don't want to delete. You can make the custom deleter simply do nothing in that case. The custom deleter will be moved right along with the pointer when you move your `unique_ptr` around.

Answer (score 2):

This function returns a dangling reference:

```
IStream&& wrap() {
    return IStream(istringstream{"test"});
}
```

The temporary object is destroyed when the function returns. Instead change the function to return by value, `IStream wrap() {`.

Also, `shared_(*owned_)` leads to a dangling reference because that refers to the memory location where the currently-owned object resides, even if that object is destroyed and the unique_ptr is later changed to own a different object.

It would be a good idea to get rid of `shared_`, and just call `owned_.get()` as needed.